# Are there any standard FPGA internal buses?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, bus

Are there any standard FPGA internal buses?
I've always used some sort of bidirectional bus between my internal blocks, but is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: What is "standard bus"? Bus is a bunch of wires. You can have some macrocells implementing some standard bus *controllers*, which are working with specific protocols. It is FPGA-specific, of course..

Comment: Any standard bus won't be a bidirectional bus these days, it'll have separate read and write data buses.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a little overview on chip internal buses, which are suitable for FPGAs:

- **Advanced Microcontroller Bus Architecture (AMBA)** from [ARM Ltd.](http://www.arm.com/)
  Current version: 5 [Specifications](http://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/amba-specifications.php)
  Further reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture)

  Commonly known buses in that family:

  - Adavance Peripherial Bus (APB)
  - Advanced High-performance Bus
  - Advanced Extensible Interface (AXI)
    Variants: AXI-Lite, AXI-Stream
- **Avalon** from [Altera now part of Intel](https://www.altera.com/)
  Current version from 12.2015: [Avalon Interface Specifications](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/manual/mnl_avalon_spec.pdf)
- **CoreConnect** from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/)
  Current version: 4.6 Specification (no official link found)
  Further reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoreConnect)

  Commonly known buses from that family:

  - Processor Local Bus (PLB)
  - On-chip Peripheral Bus (OPB)
- **Open Core_Protocol (OCP)** from [OCP International Partnership Association](http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/ocp)
  Current version:  3.0 [Specification](http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/ocp/ocp-license-agreement)
  Further reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Core_Protocol)
- **WishBone** from [OpenCores.org](http://opencores.org/)
  Current version B4: [Specification](http://cdn.opencores.org/downloads/wbspec_b4.pdf)
  Further reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishbone_(computer_bus))

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is the [wishbone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishbone_(computer_bus)) bus. Most modular IP cores you can find (e.g. on [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/)) use it.

Altera uses a variant, which is very close: the [Avalon](https://www.altera.com/literature/manual/mnl_avalon_spec.pdf) bus.

Comment: AXI bus on Xilinx.

Answer (score 3):

Most new IP uses the [AXI bus](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_ref_guide/v13_4/ug761_axi_reference_guide.pdf), which is derived from the [Advanced Microcontroller Bus Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture) introduced by ARM to support SoC designs. Newer FPGAs that include hard-core ARM processors pretty much use AXI exclusively.